# Guarantee all logs go to file

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I need to set up logging so it will always log to a file, no matter what a user or other programmer might setLevel too.  For instance I have this logger set up:

initialize_logging.py

```py
import logging

filename="./files/logs/attribution.log", level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger('attribution')

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s: %(message)s')
fh = logging.FileHandler('./files/logs/attribution.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)

ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
ch.setFormatter(formatter)

logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(fh)
logger.addHandler(ch)
```

then I have this file:

main.py

```py
%load_ext autotime
import initialize_logging
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('attribution')
logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
logger.info('TEST')
```

The above results in nothing being logged to my file and nothing being output.

However in main, if I `setLevel(logging.INFO)` then everything gets written to file and to the sterrout (I'm using a jupyter notebook so it prints on screen immediatly.)

The behavior I would like is that the user of my notebook can `setLevel` to determine what they want to see printed on screen but no matter what all logs get sent to the log file.

How do I do this?

Comment: Two handlers? One for the screen and one for the file?

Comment: @wwii - I thought I was doing that...

Comment: It seems you are confusing loggers and handlers. What you want is that the user sets the level on the StreamHandler and not on the logger. If they do that it has the effect you want. If you provide only one logger, and allow the user to change the level on that logger, it's simply impossible to still get all logs. You need to change the basic setup to get what you want, and think about what exactly you want to expose to the user.

Comment: If you look at the flow chart in the [logging how-to](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-flow) it is pretty clear that if a logger is not enabled for the level of the call it just stops. The source for the module backs that up. If your users change the logger to a higher level you won't get the file logs. Maybe a logging.Logger subclass with setLevel overridden and a Logger._cache with True values for all levels and a logging.Manager subclass with _clear_cache overridden.

Comment: Or maybe only logging.Logger.isEnabledFor needs to be overridden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Logger subclass that is enabled for all levels and set it as the LoggerClass. Override the isEnabledFor function to return True regardless of the Logger's level. Override the setLevel function to find all of the Logger's StreamHandlers and set their level to be the same as the Logger. The behavior you want will rely on the level set for the handlers.

logging_init.py

```
class AllLevels(logging.Logger):
    def isEnabledFor(self,level):
        """
        Is this logger enabled for level 'level'?
        """
        return True
    def setLevel(self,level):
        super().setLevel(level)
        for h in self.handlers:
            if isinstance(h,logging.StreamHandler):
                h.setLevel(self.level)

filename="attribution.log"

logging.setLoggerClass(AllLevels)

logger = logging.getLogger('attribution')

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s: %(message)s')
fh = logging.FileHandler(filename)
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)

ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
ch.setFormatter(formatter)

logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(fh)
logger.addHandler(ch)
```

---

**caveat**: I have not tried to think of all or any ways that this could go wrong. I only attempted to create the behavior.

---

Maybe instead of setting all StreamHandlers to the same level as the logger, only set a StreamHandler with a specific name.

---

Nothing will stop someone from inspecting the logger; finding the handlers; arbitrarily changing their levels. Maybe use a FileHandler subclass with its setLevel function overridden.

```
class AlwaysFileHandler(logging.FileHandler):
    def setLevel(self,level):
        """
        Set the logging level of this handler to DEBUG.
        """
        self.level = logging.DEBUG
```

Comment: A big downside of this is that it changes the default behaviour of pythons logging, so if the user wants to configure their own logging they are now gonna be very confused.

Comment: There are probably ways around the limitations imposed by this solution.